# How to derive $\nabla_{\mu} T^{\mu\nu}=\frac{1}{\sqrt {-g}}\partial_{\mu}(\sqrt{-g}\,T^{\mu\nu})$?

Tags: general-relativity, differential-geometry, tensor-calculus, differentiation, stress-energy-momentum-tensor

This $$\nabla_{\mu} T^{\mu\nu}=\frac{1}{\sqrt {-g}}\partial_{\mu}(\sqrt{-g}\,T^{\mu\nu})\tag{3.39}$$ is from a textbook on general relativity on black hole Vaidya metric, where only non-zero term of stress-energy tensor is $$T_{vv}=\frac{f(v)}{4\pi}e^{2\phi(r,t)}\tag{3.38}$$ and metric given by $$ds^2=2drdv-h(r,v)dv^2.\tag{3.37}$$
source: pg 16 of [Black Holes From A to Z](https://www.semanticscholar.org/paper/Black-Holes-from-A-to-Z-Strominger/13b89fc71d3efe1a97fc6fdded10011a1dd2323e#paper-header) ([web.archive.org link](https://web.archive.org/web/20170209105844/https://scholar.harvard.edu/files/yshi/files/physics_211r_-_black_holes_final.pdf))

I found this is similar to the Christoffel connection trick $$\Gamma^\mu_{\mu\nu}=\frac{1}{\sqrt{|g|}}\partial_{\nu}\sqrt{|g|}.$$ but I'm not sure how they are related.

(My attempt was: $$\nabla_{\mu} T^{\mu\nu}=\partial_{\mu} T^{\mu\nu}+\Gamma^\mu_{\mu\gamma}T^{\gamma\nu}+\Gamma^\nu_{\mu\gamma}T^{\mu\gamma}=...,$$ but this would give us 3 terms instead of one.)

Also I'm not sure whether the formula $\nabla_{\mu} T^{\mu\nu}=\frac{1}{\sqrt {-g}}\partial_{\mu}(\sqrt{-g}\,T^{\mu\nu})$ is a general result from GR or specific to this metric.

Comment: You're right that in general the equation doesn't hold (it only does for the divergence of a vector). Is there more details in the textbook, e.g. for the specific metric?

Answer (score 2):

The situation that I am familiar with is when you combine the  energy momentum tensor "covariant conservation"
$$
0=\nabla_\mu T^{\mu\nu} 
$$
equation
with a Killing vector $\xi$ obeying  $\nabla_\mu\xi_\nu+\nabla_\nu \xi_\mu=0$ to get
$$
0=\nabla_\mu (T^{\mu\nu}\xi_\nu)=0.
$$
Then $T^{\mu\nu}\xi_\nu$ is  a vector, so
$$
0=\nabla_\mu (T^{\mu\nu}\xi_\nu)= \frac {1}{\sqrt g} \partial_\mu (\sqrt g T^{\mu\nu}\xi_\nu).
$$
This tells us that
$$
\int_{x^0=t} \sqrt g T^{0\nu}\xi_\nu
$$
is independent of the time-slice $t$.  To get a genuine conserved quantity you need an actual  symmetry, and the isometry $\xi^\mu$ provides it.